# Ubuntu server behind a firewall

Tags: apt, server, firewall, ip, add-apt-repository

I have a problem regarding a server behind a firewall, essentially, the whole internet is blocked, and I can't use the "add-apt-repository", problems like "X user or team does not exist", I can't use wget to download anything, mostly, everything is blocked. I have reached to the security team to give the server full internet access, but they refused, they can only allow certain IPs from accessing the firewall, and they asked me to send them a list of IPs to unblock from the firewall, but I don't exactly know what should I send them, is it even possible? Is there a list of IPs that I can send them to add the desired repos? assuming that I'm trying to add "ondrej php" to install php8.0. Are there alternatives solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select uncommented lines with repository URLs from your configuration file for the apt:

```
grep -v -e "^#" -e "^$" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Get the names of the repository servers (FQDN) from the URL.

Example of command output:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
```

The FQDN is `cz.archive.ubuntu.com` in my example.

Get the IP address of the server(s) using the PC command `dig` (Linux) or `nslookup` (Windows) or Android application (e.g. Net Analyzer). The device must be connected to the Internet in this moment:

```
dig cz.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Visit the [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) page and search for repository URLs. The first in my list should be the right.

- https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu
- https://deb.sury.org
- http://php.net/

The FQDN is `ppa.launchpadcontent.net`.
Resolve the IP address from the name using similar way as described above.

Send all IP addresses you have got to your security team to whitelist the TCP port 80 (and eventually 443) for them.